# why can't access to django admin , the server quit immediately

Tags: django, python-3.x

i currently work on a project , i want to build it with `django 3.0.2` `python version 3.7`, but after running the server

```
python manage.py runserver
```

it will quit immediately when i try to access the `admin` url without raise any error , and even i havn't do any changes in my new app ,and also tried  `django version 2x` it worked as i expected .
i tried to remove and reinstall django , but still give the same output , 
thanks for advice

Comment: You will need to leave some code that shows your django `/admin` endpoint so that people can attempt to start helping you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're very likely to be running into this issue:

[Python 3.7 crashes after trying to visit admin page on Windows and MacOS](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/31067).

The solution is to upgrade to Python version 3.7.1 or higher.

Comment: i have multi projects created with python 3.7 if i upgrade the python version still i will be able to make changes in my projects without losing them

Comment: Yes, your project files will not be affected.